# Create exe from nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, raspberry-pi3

I have nodejs Project on Raspberry pi.
What should I do to create .exe for Project so that my project run as a desktop applications on linux as well as on Windows.

Comment: A `*.exe` file is a Windows executable; can you elaborate or share a link to an authoritative source that states you should be able to run this same executable natively on Linux as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make exe files from a node.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173232/how-to-make-exe-files-from-a-node-js-app)

Answer (score 0):

It won't be an exe or a desktop application but you could create a .bat file that runs the javascript file that you need to run. Additionally you could create a shortcut of that .bat file on the desktop.

This way at least you would be able to click the shortcut and start running your app.
You can use this link as a reference of how to achieve this: [Run node server with a bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220477/run-node-server-with-a-bat-file)

**EDIT:**
It seems batch files are Windows only.
The equivalent of a batch file in Linux would be a Shell Script.
See this link for more info: [enter link description here](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-shell-scripting.html)

Comment: Is it possible to run .bat file on raspberry pi also?

Comment: It seems to be called a Shell Script on Linux. Could be used for the same purpose here.
See this link: https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-shell-scripting.html